# Thousands of stored procedures calls using DbContext within fire-and-forget method

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

We have existing functionality in .NET framework where we log almost every line of huge data processing. We are using ADO.NET to insert data into a database table.

However, we are now converting applications to use EF Core and ASP.NET Core Web API. Although we have to use existing stored procedures. Below are the code snippet to log each data. We have to log everything but in a fire a forget method so that actual flow is not impacted.

Initially I thought to use singleton while registering the `LogDbContext` in `Startup.cs`, however, I'm getting this exception with singleton:

> An attempt was made to use the context while it is being configured. A DbContext instance cannot be used inside 'OnConfiguring' since it is still being configured at this point. This can happen if a second operation is started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

When I changed `Singleton` to `Scoped`/`Transient`, I no longer get this exception, however now I get a different error:

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

Can anyone please share some suggestion how to handle this situation using `DbContext` in fire and forget method?

```
private void Log(LogCategory category, string message, ProcessType type)
{
    var log = BuildErrorObj(category, message, string.Empty, null, type);

    _= Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await LogError(log);
        });
}

private async Task<bool> LogError(LogData log)
{
    try
    {
        List<SqlParameter> parms = new List<SqlParameter>
                { 
                    // Create parameters    
                   new SqlParameter("@ErrorId", log.ErrorIdentifier),
                   new SqlParameter("@Application", log.Application),
                   new SqlParameter("@Host", log.Host),
                   new SqlParameter("@Type", log.Type),
                   new SqlParameter("@Source", log.Source),
                   new SqlParameter("@Message", log.Message),
                   new SqlParameter("@User", log.User),
                   new SqlParameter("@ThreadID", log.ThreadID),
                   new SqlParameter("@Process", log.Process),
                   new SqlParameter("@stackTrace", log.StackTrace),
                   new SqlParameter("@eventid", log.EventId),
                   new SqlParameter("@category", log.Category),
                   new SqlParameter("@TimeUtc", log.TimeUtc)
            };

        string sql = "EXEC [AppObject].[usp_LogError] @ErrorId, @Application, @Host, @Type, @Source, @Message, @User, " +
                                                "@ThreadID, @Process, @stackTrace, @eventid, @category, @TimeUtc";

        using var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
        var logContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<LogDbContext>();

        await logContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(sql, parms.ToArray());

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex?.Message);
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddDbContext<LogDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LogDbProvider")), ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
```

Comment: You should never run a fire & forget method from a web application. If the application pool is refreshed the process dies and also the web server is busy enough hosting the site. This is what Hangfire was made for.

Answer (score 2):

> When I changed `Singleton` to `Scoped/Transient`, I no longer get this exception.

Please, only use scope lifetime with every `DbContext`, otherwise, I always raise weird exception (conflict tracking, object as `Singleton`, difference `DbContext` for `Transient` (if you intend to use repository pattern or inject `DbContext` somewhere with scope `Scoped/Transient`))

> We have existing functionality in .NET framework where we log almost every line of huge data processing. We are using ADO.NET to insert data into a database table.

As I understand it right, the whole processing data can be scoped to one lifetime right ? (I know we'll log every line of data process).

If so, create a separately scope for the data process by using `IServiceScopeFactory`. And use it like

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    using var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();
    var dependency = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<YourService>();

    dependency.DoYourWork();
    // Fill the res logic and logging
});
```

So why that's so complicated ?
Cause of Asp.net core manage your Http Request lifetime scope automatically. What would happen if the request finish (fire and forget the data process), then the data process make use of `DbContext` that got serve for the previous Http Request ? Nasty Error.

And don't forget, take every dependency in manually created scope, never use any service that relate to `ServiceProvider` outside, otherwise, error would randomly raise(it depend on how quick the process and http request finish).

That's what @Nicola Biada is missing.

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

If a `DbContext` per data process still dry-out your connection pool, then i highly suggest that you should use `BackgroundService` to execute the data process, might be 5-10 process at the same point, and keep the loop as long as your data process flow not yet complete. That way it will just keep 5-10 connection at a time.

For even better approach, I suggest an implement of message bus, separate the background to another app instance. And background consumer would consume message as re-present for each data-process by your specific config (5-10-20 message consume at a time, timeout for each message,...)

Comment: I respect every approach to a problem, but this is just your approach and the answer (talking about background service) is partially out of scope and, I think partially inapplicable, but is my opinion. I respect everyone.

Comment: Yup... except the fact that Mousam clearly ask for converting applications to use EF Core and ASP.NET Core Web API. And just make an example, `LogError(log)` make use of `DbContext` dependency. then just put a `await Task.Delay(500)` to slightly describe the execution time to see the error in your example to see exception.
Just to put a notice to people for giving some short of kind to the answer... Wish nobody have gone through hours debugging followed by uncompleted guidance.
We can do better than that, obviously

Comment: @GordonKhanhNg. could you provide how `BackgroundService` should look like?

Comment: I believe [this](https://michaelceber.medium.com/net-core-web-api-how-to-correctly-fire-and-forget-database-commands-from-controller-end-point-cad7a879630) is what you looking for (asp.net core)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove any await / async and maintains the Task.

In this mode you can use something like:

```cs
Task.Run(() => LogError(log)).ConfigureAwait(false)
```

In case you cannot remove async/await take a look to this package to create fire and forget asynchronous calls:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading/

Docs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.threading.tplextensions.forget?view=visualstudiosdk-2017

Comment: You absolutely missing out the Scope lifetime in asp.net core. I just point it out below, might be you want to take a look ?
And beside, `ConfigureAwait(false)` is just doing nothing in asp.net core cause of the fact that  a `SynchronizeContext` not exists there.

Comment: None are talking about lifetime. synchronize context is another concept for the problem above